# How to move COMP-5 values to a Numeric field?

Tags: cobol

I am trying to move a COMP-5 variable(which I am receiving from some other system) to a numeric field. I have noticed when I display the COMP-5 variable I can see the value but when I try to move it the value in COMP-5 variable becomes zeros.I don't have any experience working with COMP-5. Can someone help me with this?

Code:

```
   09 O-Xid.                                                
     12 O-Xid2-length                   PIC S9999 COMP-5 SYNC.                                                       
     12 O-Xid2                          PIC X(255).   
   09 WS-O-Xid.                                             
     12 WS-O-Xid2-length                PIC 9999.        
     12 WS-O-Xid2                       PIC X(255).      
      
                                                              
MOVE O-Xid2-length         TO WS-O-Xid2-length       
MOVE O-Xid2                TO WS-O-Xid2
```

Comment: Just to make sure: the `O-Xid2-length`-field you receive is 2 bytes?

Comment: @piet.t Thank you for your answer!
Yes I am receiving 2 bytes in the O-Xid2-length. I am still not bale to resolve this. Any pointers where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @Simon Yes Thank you for your help! I went through the docs and the problem was with the picture clause it was 9(4) for my working storage variable but due to the copybook variable being comp-5 it was actually 32 bytes. When I chnaged it to X(32) I could see the correct value being populated.

Comment: So your `COMP-5` question was solved by not using `COMP-5` at all?
Note: `COMP-5` makes the byte-size less, not more; using `PIC X(32)` sounds very suspicious...

Comment: @Simon COMP-5 was the incoming data from the other system. The variable used in my cobol program were not COMP-5.But yes when I increased the field size then only I was able to see the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MOVE` as you've used does any necessary conversions between any numeric `USAGE`, as long as the data is valid.

The code misses the actual `DISPLAY` statement, I *assume* you've tested for valid data with `DISPLAY O-Xid2-length` (please specify the output).

The most likely reason that the target does not contain the source value would be:
the COBOL environment you use (you've neither specified the compiler not the options you used) doesn't truncate COMP-5 values according to ANSI/ISO - so it may contain "10000" and is then truncated on the `MOVE` because the target can't hold that value (standard truncation happening here keeps only the last 4 digits).
All other cases get to "there is not the data in the field that you think" - again: please specify both the ´DISPLAY` statement and the result.

Additional info to `TRUNC(BIN)`: according to the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=options-trunc):

- `BINARY` sending fields are handled as halfwords, fullwords, or doublewords when the receiver is numeric
- `DISPLAY` will convert the entire content of binary fields with no truncation.

`DISPLAY` would also show a value like 30000, I *think* the `MOVE` would in this case result to a zero value.

---

For *other* usages, it would be possible that the value stored in the variable is actually not valid data, but this does not apply to `BINARY` (or `COMP-5` items). In this case the COBOL environment used could do some auto-correction on `DISPLAY`, but on `MOVE` just change the invalid value to `ZERO`; to check that you'd need to use either a debugger or otherwise hex-dump the value received.

Comment: `COMP-5`  is "native binary" - no such thing as "invalid `COMP-5` data" or "sign part" - I guess you were thinking of `COMP-3`. Looking at the `DISPLAY`-output in HEX-mode would be a good idea.

Comment: @Simon Thank you for your answer!
The compliler option that I am using is  TRUNC(BIN) ? would this have any effect on the data representation?

Comment: @piet.t you are correct of course, I've adjusted the answer with additional link to `trunc(bin) `.